# Printing pages using db paths to files

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Imagine a database application such as a expense report billing system.
I have it developed in asp.net with SQL server.  Imagine a one to many relationship where one expense report has multiple attachments (receipts) such as paths to images or PDFs etc.  Currently on a grid I show hyperlinks to view the attachments, so you can click the link to open say a scanned PDF.  I want to add a print all feature that goes through each attachment to print it.

If the paths are stored on a network share \my server\myfiles and the database just has a link to this path with the filename is it possible to loop through and use something like window.print to print each file?  How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Problem with window.print is it will have a dialog prompt for every item. This would be painful for the user.

Best thing you can do is generate a file on the server [probably pdf] that has everything combined and print just that.

Comment: Agreed. If all the documents are PDF, grab an open source .NET PDF library and use it to combine all documents into 1, then render that out to the client, which will allow them to print the entire PDF.